Calculating N evenly spaced points on a ringed torus surface(not randomly)
I have been trying to find a optimised solution for calculating the x, y, z of a point that lives along the surface of the torus and is equally spaced out like other points. The naive approach is to have a vector in a fixed point and rotating it and at the tip of that vector we add circles that are rotated as well to form a torus. While simple this is unoptimised due to the fact its O(n^2) solution.
I had encountered the same problem when wanting to distribute N points roughly evenly spaced along a sphere surface. Which the naive approach did O(n^2) but found later about the fibonacci lattice and a specific algorithm which shot the time down to O(n). And i basically want such solution for the torus(if possible of course).
Known Variables:

Inner Radius(the torus's hole)
Outer Radius(the torus's size)
The amount of points

I don't care right now in terms of the code, but more so of the math aspect & how expensive is the method.
TLDR: find an efficient way to distribute N points roughly evenly on the torus's surface. Knowing these 3 variables

Are you sure that this is a [tag:linear-algebra] question?

Well, i mean i have to find xyz, which has to do with coordinates so we are working with vectors
EDIT: Im planning to do rotations once i get an efficient way of generating points in a torus surface(so this is kinda the part where its mostly linear algebra). I didn't mention it due to the fact that i want to abstract some details to further simplify the question to its core components
